# Can someone help me with this problem of finding indices of the pairs of elements of an array that sum to k?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {

    std::unordered_map<int, int> nMap;

    int a[] = {3,4,5,6,5,7,4};
    int k = 10;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        int rem = k - a[i];
        if(nMap.find(rem) != nMap.end()){
            printf("(%d,%d)\n",nMap[rem], i);
        }

        nMap.insert(std::pair<int,int>(a[i],i));
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program I have used a hash-map to find the indices of the pairs of the elements giving the sum equal to the k. And it's working fine for the above code and gives me the required pairs

```
(1,3)
(2,4)
(0,5)
(3,6)
```

Note: These are the indices of the elements that actually add up to k.

But, this does work correctly for the input `int a[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1}; int k = 2` the output given is:

```
(0,1)
(0,2)
(0,3)
(0,4)
(0,5)
(0,6)
```

However according to me I guess the output must have all pairs namely (1,2),(1,3)...(5,6).
What is the correct program for the above problem?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: For each element, you `find` one element to complete the sum. You need to add more code to find the other elements that would also complete the sum.

Comment: `for(size_t i = 0; i < std::size(a)-1; ++i) for(size_t j=i+1; j < std::size(a); ++j) if(a[i]+a[j]==k) ...` - no `map` needed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That takes O(n^2) time. Using map it's in O(n) time

Comment: @SomeshwarRoychowdhury I'd compare real times instead of complexity. For these small arrays a full search may be quicker than the map lookup - but even if it's not, it does the correct thing while the map lookup you have now does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input `1,1,1,1,1,1,1` produces 6+5+4+3+2+1 = 21 = N * (N-1) / 2 = N²/2 - N/2 outputs:

(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(0, 4)
(0, 5)
(0, 6)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
(1, 6)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)
(2, 6)
(3, 4)
(3, 5)
(3, 6)
(4, 5)
(4, 6)
(5, 6)

You need an algorithm with complexity O(N²) to produce such output. Your code doesn't work because a code with complexity O(N) can't produce this much output.

Here is a more performant solution using unordered map:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 7> a{3,4,5,6,5,7,4};
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<std::size_t>> nMap;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        nMap[a[i]].push_back(i);
    }
    int k = 10;
    for (const auto &el : nMap) {
        if (nMap.find(k - el.first) == nMap.end()) continue;
        for (const auto &left : el.second) {
            for (const auto &right : nMap.at(k - el.first)) {
                if (left < right) std::cout << '(' << left << ',' << right << ")\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I filled a map with all indices for one value. Now I can access all indices in O(1) for a target value. I iterate all values in the map and print all pairs of values.

Comment: What is this principle defining the number of outputs possible from an algorithm ?

Comment: @SomeshwarRoychowdhury It's a basic mathematical problem. There are N*(N-1) 2-element-subsets of a set. That's twice the number of outputs if all elements fit to all other elements. It's called competitive programming but it's not competitive programming. It's competitive mathematics with basic programming.